# How grunt watch files in sub folders?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

My code folders and files are like this, you never know how many sub folders in it:

```
js/sub1/a.js
js/sub2/b.js
js/sub3/sub31/c.js
js/sub4/sub41/sub411/d.js
```

Here is part of the Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
        src: {
            files: ['js/*.js'],
            tasks: []
        }
    }
});
```

Grunt can't watch the changes of my all JavaScript files by using `'js/*.js'`. So how to write the correct file path expression?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Per the [official documentation on file globbing](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns), to watch for changes for files of a certain file type in the directory path and its subdirectories, you'll want:

```
files: ['js/**/*.js']
```

Comment: one thing I noticed - you have to re-run `grunt watch` if you add some files to these paths and its more than a few levels deep